# Волновой алгоритм. Запуск волны

Tags: java

Нужно написать волновой алгоритм. Не получается у меня пустить волну. Пытаюсь её пустить с помощью рекурсии. Код работает, но показывает только один кратчайший путь или вообще непонятно что показывает) 
Через рекурсию доходит до границ массива (вправо), после чего не пойму, как сделать, чтобы действия вернулись к самому начал и рекурсия шла в другую сторону (вниз, вверх).

```
public void findPath(int y, int x, int d) {
    mas[y][x] = d;

    for (int i = y - 1; i <= y + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = x - 1; j < x + 1; j++) {
            if (x < width - 1 && mas[y][x + 1] == 0) {
                findPath(y, x + 1, d + 1);
            }
            if (y > 0 && mas[y - 1][x] == 0) {
                findPath(y - 1, x, d + 1);
            }
            if (y < height && mas[y + 1][x] == 0) {
                findPath(y + 1, x, d + 1);
            }
            if (x > 0 && mas[y][x - 1] == 0) {
                findPath(y, x - 1, d + 1);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: мне кажется или волновой алгоритм работает без рекурсии? А на основе поиска в ширину?

Comment: Через рекурсию нельзя сделать?

Comment: @Rynkovoy можно) но смысла нету

Comment: Нужно найти просто кратчайший путь. Почитал в интернете про волновой алгоритм. Сначала нужно же пустить "волну" (цифры эти). Мне чего-то показалось, что это через рекурсию нужно делать.

Comment: @pavel А как тогда пустить волну можно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То что вы написали не имеет отношения к поиску в ширину, да и в глубину тоже.  Для поиска кратчайшего пути нужно использовать поиск в ширину на основе очереди. В качестве очереди можно использовать `ArrayList` примерный код (только исправил).

```
public void findPath(int x,int y) {
    ArrayList<Pair<Integer,Integer>> queue = new ArrayList<>();
    queue.add(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(x,y));
    mas[x][y] = 1;
    while (queue.size() > 0)  {
        Pair<Integer,Integer> cur = queue.remove(queue.size() - 1);
        int x = cur.x;
        int y = cur.y;
//
        if (x < width - 1 && mas[x + 1][y] == 0) {
                queue.add(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(x+1, y);
                mas[x+1][y] = 1;
        }
        if (x > 0 && mas[x - 1][y] == 0) {
                queue.add(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(x-1,y);
                mas[x-1][y] = 1;
        }
        if (y < height - 1 && mas[x][y+1] == 0) {
                queue.add(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(x, y + 1);
                mas[x][y+1] = 1;
        }
        if (y > 0 && mas[x][y-1] == 0) {
                queue.add(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(x, y - 1);
                mas[x][y-1] = 1;
        }
//
    }
}
```

Кстати у вас с индексами каша полная. Но думаю доделать сумеете.

Comment: с очередями в своем учебном процесса ни разу не сталкивался, поэтому даже не знаю, что это такое в программировании) Спасибо, Вам, большое. Буду пытаться разобрать код. 
Только вопрос еще один, какой все таки нужен алгоритм для поиска пути: в ширину или волновой?)

Comment: @Rynkovoy волнового алгоритма не существует

Comment: это вопрос терминологии, поиск в ширину, BFS и волновой обход грфа это почти одно и тоже.

Comment: @PavelMayorov на хабре и википедии описывают его

Comment: @pavel окей, понял, спасибо)
 int x = cur.x;
        int y = cur.y; а что это означает?

Comment: @Rynkovoy проблема "волнового" алгоритма в том, что разные авторы понимают под ним поиск в глубину, поиск в ширину, алгоритм Дейкстры и алгоритм Алгоритм Беллмана — Форда

Comment: @PavelMayorov ага, тут вкурил. буду знать, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Пример на С#. Объектная модель.

[image: Скрин консоли]

[GitHub](https://github.com/Cuprumbur/Lee-algorithm)

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Finder
{

public class LeeAlgorithm
{
    public int[,] ArrayGraph { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Начало пути с конца списка
    /// </summary>
    public List<Tuple<int, int>> Path { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Heidth { get; private set; }
    public bool PathFound { get; private set; }
    public int LengthPath { get { return Path.Count; } }

    private int _step;
    private bool _finishingCellMarked;
    private int _finishPointI;
    private int _finishPointJ;

    /// <summary>
    /// Инициализирует новый экземпляр объекта с полем и указанием начальной точки
    /// </summary>
    public LeeAlgorithm(int startX, int startY, int[,] array)
    {
        ArrayGraph = array;
        Width = ArrayGraph.GetLength(0);
        Heidth = ArrayGraph.GetLength(1);
        SetStarCell(startX, startY);
        PathFound = PathSearch();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Инициализирует новый экземпляр объекта с полем. Начальной точка установлена в массиве
    /// </summary>
    public LeeAlgorithm(int[,] array)
    {
        ArrayGraph = array;
        Width = ArrayGraph.GetLength(0);
        Heidth = ArrayGraph.GetLength(1);
        int startX;
        int startY;
        FindStartCell(out startX, out startY);
        SetStarCell(startX, startY);
        PathFound = PathSearch();

    }

    private void FindStartCell(out int startX, out int startY)
    {
        int w = Width;
        int h = Heidth;

        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                if (ArrayGraph[i, j] == (int)Figures.StartPosition)
                {
                    startX = i;
                    startY = j;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new AggregateException("Нет начальной точки");
    }

    private void SetStarCell(int startX, int startY)
    {
        if (startX > this.ArrayGraph.GetLength(0) || startX < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Неправильная координата x");
        if (startY > this.ArrayGraph.GetLength(1) || startY < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Неправильная координата x");
        //Пометить стартовую ячейку d:= 0
        _step = 0;
        ArrayGraph[startX, startY] = _step;
    }

    private bool PathSearch()
    {
        if (WavePropagation())
            if (RestorePath())
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    // Есть. Ортогональный путь
    // Todo. Ортогонально-диагональный путь

    /// <summary>
    /// Распространение волны
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool WavePropagation()
    {
        //ЦИКЛ
        //  ДЛЯ каждой ячейки loc, помеченной числом d
        //    пометить все соседние свободные непомеченные ячейки числом d + 1
        //  КЦ
        //  d := d + 1
        //ПОКА(финишная ячейка не помечена) И(есть возможность распространения волны)

        int w = Width;
        int h = Heidth;

        bool finished = false;
        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
                {
                    if (ArrayGraph[i, j] == _step)
                    {
                        // Пометить все соседние свободные непомеченные ячейки числом d + 1
                        if (i != w - 1)
                            if (ArrayGraph[i + 1, j] == (int)Figures.EmptySpace) ArrayGraph[i + 1, j] = _step + 1;
                        if (j != h - 1)
                            if (ArrayGraph[i, j + 1] == (int)Figures.EmptySpace) ArrayGraph[i, j + 1] = _step + 1;
                        if (i != 0)
                            if (ArrayGraph[i - 1, j] == (int)Figures.EmptySpace) ArrayGraph[i - 1, j] = _step + 1;
                        if (j != 0)
                            if (ArrayGraph[i, j - 1] == (int)Figures.EmptySpace) ArrayGraph[i, j - 1] = _step + 1;

                        // Путь до финиша проложен
                        if (i < w - 1)
                            if (ArrayGraph[i + 1, j] == (int)Figures.Destination)
                            {
                                _finishPointI = i + 1;
                                _finishPointJ = j;
                                finished = true;
                            }
                        if (j < h - 1)
                            if (ArrayGraph[i, j + 1] == (int)Figures.Destination)
                            {
                                _finishPointI = i;
                                _finishPointJ = j + 1;
                                finished = true;
                            }
                        if (i > 0)
                            if (ArrayGraph[i - 1, j] == (int)Figures.Destination)
                            {
                                _finishPointI = i - 1;
                                _finishPointJ = j;
                                finished = true;
                            }
                        if (j > 0)
                            if (ArrayGraph[i, j - 1] == (int)Figures.Destination)
                            {
                                _finishPointI = i;
                                _finishPointJ = j - 1;
                                finished = true;
                            }
                    }

                }
            }
            _step++;
            //ПОКА(финишная ячейка не помечена) И(есть возможность распространения волны)
        } while (!finished && _step < w * h);
        _finishingCellMarked = finished;
        return finished;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Восстановление пути
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool RestorePath()
    {
        // ЕСЛИ финишная ячейка помечена
        // ТО
        //   перейти в финишную ячейку
        //   ЦИКЛ
        //     выбрать среди соседних ячейку, помеченную числом на 1 меньше числа в текущей ячейке
        //     перейти в выбранную ячейку и добавить её к пути
        //   ПОКА текущая ячейка — не стартовая
        //   ВОЗВРАТ путь найден
        // ИНАЧЕ
        //   ВОЗВРАТ путь не найден
        if (!_finishingCellMarked)
            return false;

        int w = Width;
        int h = Heidth;
        int i = _finishPointI;
        int j = _finishPointJ;
        Path = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        AddToPath(i, j);

        do
        {
            if (i < w - 1)
                if (ArrayGraph[i + 1, j] == _step - 1)
                {
                    AddToPath(++i, j);
                }
            if (j < h - 1)
                if (ArrayGraph[i, j + 1] == _step - 1)
                {
                    AddToPath(i, ++j);
                }
            if (i > 0)
                if (ArrayGraph[i - 1, j] == _step - 1)
                {
                    AddToPath(--i, j);
                }
            if (j > 0)
                if (ArrayGraph[i, j - 1] == _step - 1)
                {
                    AddToPath(i, --j);
                }
            _step--;
        } while (_step != 0);
        return true;
    }

    private void AddToPath(int x, int y)
    {
        Path.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y));
    }
}
public enum Figures
{
    StartPosition = 0,
    EmptySpace = -1,
    Destination = -2,
    Path = -3,
    Barrier = -4
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int heigth = 10;
        const int width = 18;

        int[,] my = new int[heigth, width];
        for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                var rand = new Random(unchecked((int)DateTime.Now.Millisecond));
                if (rand.Next(100) > 70)
                    my[i, j] = (int)Figures.Barrier;
                else
                    my[i, j] = (int)Figures.EmptySpace;
            }
        }
        var random = new Random(unchecked((int)DateTime.Now.Millisecond));
        my[random.Next(heigth), random.Next(width)] = (int)Figures.StartPosition;
        my[random.Next(heigth), random.Next(width)] = (int)Figures.Destination;
        Print(my);

        LeeAlgorithm li = new LeeAlgorithm(my);
        Console.WriteLine(li.PathFound);
        if (li.PathFound)
        {
            foreach (var item in li.Path)
            {
                if (item == li.Path.Last())
                    my[item.Item1, item.Item2] = (int)Figures.StartPosition;
                else if (item == li.Path.First())
                    my[item.Item1, item.Item2] = (int)Figures.Destination;
                else
                    my[item.Item1, item.Item2] = (int)Figures.Path;
            }
            Print(li.ArrayGraph);
            Console.WriteLine("Длина " + li.LengthPath);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Путь не найден");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void Print(int[,] array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("***");
        string msg = string.Empty;
        int x = array.GetLength(0);
        int y = array.GetLength(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                switch (array[i, j])
                {
                    case (int)Figures.Path: msg = string.Format("{0,3}", "+"); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow; break;
                    case (int)Figures.StartPosition: msg = string.Format("{0,3}", "s"); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green; break;
                    case (int)Figures.Destination: msg = string.Format("{0,3}", "d"); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; break;
                    case (int)Figures.EmptySpace: msg = string.Format("{0,3}", "'"); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue; break;
                    case (int)Figures.Barrier: msg = string.Format("{0,3}", "*"); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue; break;
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                    case 8:
                    case 9:
                    case 10:
                    case 11:
                    case 12:
                    case 13:
                    case 14:
                    case 15:
                    case 16:
                    case 17:
                    case 18:
                    case 19:
                    case 20:
                        msg = string.Format("{0,3}", array[i, j]); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray; break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                Console.Write(msg);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}

}
```